# Помогите допилить костыль (Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException)

Tags: c#

Выбивает ошибку < Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException > в консоли, когда игра якобы ближется к концу.

```
class X_O
{
    static char One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine;
    static int Enter;
    static int PCEnter;

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Monitor();
        Enters();
    }

    static void Monitor()
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("    --- --- --- ");
        Console.WriteLine("   ┆ {0} ┆ {1} ┆ {2} ┆", One, Two, Three);
        Console.WriteLine("    --- --- --- ");
        Console.WriteLine("   ┆ {0} ┆ {1} ┆ {2} ┆", Four, Five, Six);
        Console.WriteLine("    --- --- --- ");
        Console.WriteLine("   ┆ {0} ┆ {1} ┆ {2} ┆", Seven, Eight, Nine);
        Console.WriteLine("    --- --- --- ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }

    static void PC()
    {
        Random Num = new Random();
        PCEnter = Num.Next(1,9);
        switch (PCEnter)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        if (One == 'X' || One == 'O') PC();
                        else One = 'O'; Main(); break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        if (Two == 'X' || Two == 'O') PC();
                        else Two = 'O'; Main(); break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        if (Three == 'X' || Three == 'O') PC();
                        else Three = 'O'; Main(); break;
                    }
                case 4:
                    {
                        if (Four == 'X' || Four == 'O') PC();
                        else Four = 'O'; Main(); break;
                    }
                case 5:
                    {
                        if (Five == 'X' || Five == 'O') PC();
                        else Five = 'O'; Main(); break;
                    }
                case 6:
                    {
                        if (Six == 'X' || Six == 'O') PC();
                        else Six = 'O'; Main(); break;
                    }
                case 7:
                    {
                        if (Seven == 'X' || Seven == 'O') PC();
                        else Seven = 'O'; Main(); break;
                    }
                case 8:
                    {
                        if (Eight == 'X' || Eight == 'O') PC();
                        else Eight = 'O'; Main(); break;
                    }
                case 9:
                    {
                        if (Nine == 'X' || Nine == 'O') PC();
                        else Nine = 'O'; Main(); break;
                    }
            }
            Main();
        }

    static void Enters()
    {
        Console.Write(" X_O ВАШ ХОД : ");
        try
        {
            Enter = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (Enter)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        if (One == 'X' || One == 'O') Console.Beep();
                        else One = 'X'; PC(); break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        if (Two == 'X' || Two == 'O') Console.Beep();
                        else Two = 'X'; PC(); break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        if (Three == 'X' || Three == 'O') Console.Beep();
                        else Three = 'X'; PC(); break;
                    }
                case 4:
                    {
                        if (Four == 'X' || Four == 'O') Console.Beep();
                        else Four = 'X'; PC(); break;
                    }
                case 5:
                    {
                        if (Five == 'X' || Five == 'O') Console.Beep();
                        else Five = 'X'; PC(); break;
                    }
                case 6:
                    {
                        if (Six == 'X' || Six == 'O') Console.Beep();
                        else Six = 'X'; PC(); break;
                    }
                case 7:
                    {
                        if (Seven == 'X' || Seven == 'O') Console.Beep();
                        else Seven = 'X'; PC(); break;
                    }
                case 8:
                    {
                        if (Eight == 'X' || Eight == 'O') Console.Beep();
                        else Eight = 'X'; PC(); break;
                    }
                case 9:
                    {
                        if (Nine == 'X' || Nine == 'O') Console.Beep();
                        else Nine = 'X'; PC(); break;
                    }
                default: Console.Beep(); Main(); break;
            }
            Main();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.Beep();
            Main();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Кееек]

Comment: И не удивительно, вы из `Main` вызываете `Enters`, а из `Enters` вызываете `Main`. Рекурсия однако......И между прочим нельзя из чего-то вызывать Main. Это ж точка входа.

Comment: Оу.. Я и не подумал об этом ;d
Спасибо большое)

Comment: Как вообще тогда возможно реализовать повторный вызов? ;d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как правильно заметил @Алексей Шиманский, у вы используете рекурсивный вызов без условия остановки рекурсии, которая и вызывает переполнение стека на определенном этапе.

Вообще. если есть возможность обойтись без рекурсии, лучше обойтись без нее, т.к. при вызове функции, текущее состояние программы запоминается в стек, а при глубокой рекурсии стек рано или поздно заканчивается. В вашем случае необходимо убрать вызовы `Main` и `PC` из ваших функций, и изменить функцию `Main` так, чтобы ваши функции выполнялись в цикле до определенного состояния: победа, поражение, нет свободных клеток или пока есть доступные ходы. В этом же цикле задаем последовательность ходов - кто ходит первым, кто вторым, например так:

```
static void Main()
{
    while(можно_сделать_ход)
    {
        //первый ход, в данном случае игрока
        Console.Clear();
        Monitor();
        Enters();
        //Для второго игрока придется дополнительно проверить возможность
        //хода, т.к. во-первых, максимальное количество ходов нечетное,
        //во-вторых, первый игрок мог выиграть своим ходом и дальнейшие
        //ходы не имеют смысла.
        if(можно_сделать_ход)
        {
            //второй ход
            Console.Clear();
            Monitor();
            PC();
        }
    }
}
```

замените `можно_сделать_ход` на подходящее условие.

Таким образом цикл обеспечит чередование ходов без необходимости делать рекурсивные вызовы функций и переполнения стека в результате.

Также стоит подумать об изменении функции `PC`. У вас используется генератор случайных чисел, который выбирает ход из всех ячеек на поле, не учитывая занятость ячейки. Это приведет к тому, что каждый следующий ход будет выбираться дольше, потому что генератор будет чаще выдавать номера занятых ячеек. Решить можно, заведя список доступных ячеек и на каждом ходу удалять из него использованную ячейку, а генератор случайных чисел настроить на выбор числа из диапазона 0 - `длина_списка_неиспользованных_ячеек`.

Comment: Спасибо за такое количество хороших идей, буду переделывать костыль)

Comment: @SDst пожалуйста. Если только-только учитесь, то найдите задачник А.Шень Программирование теоремы и задачи, будет полезно для изучения программирования в принципе. А потом можно и более тяжелую артиллерию подключить по мере необходимости. Тут по шарпу целый список лежит с градацией сложности материала.

Comment: Да вот только учусь, по данным видео урокам - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnV3K-pmuXwjSI_k3NrPBENNds35G72h2 (Кто-то слил этот курс с дисков на канал), пока только на 34 уроке, мало что ещё знаю, основы так немного. Вот думаю начну читать ещё "Библия C#" , да и посмотрю обязательно задачник А.Шеня)

Comment: @SDst вот тут посмотрите книжки по .NET http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416585/198316

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем как-то так уже всё реализовал, спасибо тем кто помог с ошибками ;)

```
class X_O
{
    static char One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine;
    static bool Cicle = true;
    static int PCEnter;
    static int Enter;

    static void Main()
    {
        while (Cicle)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Monitor();
            Entry();
            EntryWin();
            PCEntry();
            PCEntryWin();
        }
    }

    static void Monitor()
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("    --- --- --- ");
        Console.WriteLine("   ┆ {0} ┆ {1} ┆ {2} ┆", One, Two, Three);
        Console.WriteLine("    --- --- --- ");
        Console.WriteLine("   ┆ {0} ┆ {1} ┆ {2} ┆", Four, Five, Six);
        Console.WriteLine("    --- --- --- ");
        Console.WriteLine("   ┆ {0} ┆ {1} ┆ {2} ┆", Seven, Eight, Nine);
        Console.WriteLine("    --- --- --- ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.Write(" X_O ВАШ ХОД : ");
    }

    static void Entry()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Monitor();
            Enter = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (Enter)
            {
                case 1: if (One == 'X' || One == 'O') { Console.Beep(); Entry(); } else One = 'X'; break;
                case 2: if (Two == 'X' || Two == 'O') { Console.Beep(); Entry(); } else Two = 'X'; break;
                case 3: if (Three == 'X' || Three == 'O') { Console.Beep(); Entry(); } else Three = 'X'; break;
                case 4: if (Four == 'X' || Four == 'O') { Console.Beep(); Entry(); } else Four = 'X'; break;
                case 5: if (Five == 'X' || Five == 'O') { Console.Beep(); Entry(); } else Five = 'X'; break;
                case 6: if (Six == 'X' || Six == 'O') { Console.Beep(); Entry(); } else Six = 'X'; break;
                case 7: if (Seven == 'X' || Seven == 'O') { Console.Beep(); Entry(); } else Seven = 'X'; break;
                case 8: if (Eight == 'X' || Eight == 'O') { Console.Beep(); Entry(); } else Eight = 'X'; break;
                case 9: if (Nine == 'X' || Nine == 'O') { Console.Beep(); Entry(); } else Nine = 'X'; break;
                default: Console.Beep(); break;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.Beep();
            Entry();
        }
    }

    static void PCEntry()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Monitor();
        Random Num = new Random();
        PCEnter = Num.Next(1,9);
        switch (PCEnter)
        {
            case 1: if (One == 'X' || One == 'O') PCEntry(); else One = 'O'; break;
            case 2: if (Two == 'X' || Two == 'O') PCEntry(); else Two = 'O'; break;
            case 3: if (Three == 'X' || Three == 'O') PCEntry(); else Three = 'O'; break;
            case 4: if (Four == 'X' || Four == 'O') PCEntry(); else Four = 'O'; break;
            case 5: if (Five == 'X' || Five == 'O') PCEntry(); else Five = 'O'; break;
            case 6: if (Six == 'X' || Six == 'O') PCEntry(); else Six = 'O'; break;
            case 7: if (Seven == 'X' || Seven == 'O') PCEntry(); else Seven = 'O'; break;
            case 8: if (Eight == 'X' || Eight == 'O') PCEntry(); else Eight = 'O'; break;
            case 9: if (Nine == 'X' || Nine == 'O') PCEntry(); else Nine = 'O'; break;
            default: Console.Beep(); break;
        }
    }

    static void EntryWin()
    {
        if (One == 'X' && Two == 'X' && Three == 'X') Win();
        if (Four == 'X' && Five == 'X' && Six == 'X') Win();
        if (Seven == 'X' && Eight == 'X' && Nine == 'X') Win();
        if (One == 'X' && Four == 'X' && Seven == 'X') Win();
        if (Two == 'X' && Five == 'X' && Eight == 'X') Win();
        if (Three == 'X' && Six == 'X' && Nine == 'X') Win();
        if (One == 'X' && Five == 'X' && Nine == 'X') Win();
        if (Three == 'X' && Five == 'X' && Seven == 'X') Win();
    }

    static void PCEntryWin()
    {
        if (One == 'O' && Two == 'O' && Three == 'O') Lose();
        if (Four == 'O' && Five == 'O' && Six == 'O') Lose();
        if (Seven == 'O' && Eight == 'O' && Nine == 'O') Lose();
        if (One == 'O' && Four == 'O' && Seven == 'O') Lose();
        if (Two == 'O' && Five == 'O' && Eight == 'O') Lose();
        if (Three == 'O' && Six == 'O' && Nine == 'O') Lose();
        if (One == 'O' && Five == 'O' && Nine == 'O') Lose();
        if (Three == 'O' && Five == 'O' && Seven == 'O') Lose();
    }

    static void Win()
    {
        Cicle = false;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("   ВЫ ПОБЕДИЛИ!!!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Lose()
    {
        Cicle = false;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("   ВЫ ПРОИГРАЛИ!!!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}